# JQuery addClass not working

Tags: jquery

First of all, I checked all the newbie mistakes.  According to Firebug, that element has no class attribute set untill the addClass is called and then the class attribute is set to "".

Javacript:

```
$("#filter_banned").change(function(){
    if ($("#filter_banned").is(":checked")) $("#admin-userList").addClass("appliedFilter_banned");
    $("#admin-userList").removeClass("appliedFilter_banned");
})
```

The addclass is getting called, and then wrapping it in alert(e.length) alerts 1 so I know it not only finds admin-userList, but also calls the if thingy.

Also, #admin-userList is a `<ul>` tag.

And now here is my CSS:

```
.appliedFilter_banned .user.banned { display: none; }
```

Is supposed to just be a list displaying all the site users, and a checkbox to hide any ones that have been banned.

Comment: What type of element is `#admin-userList`?

Comment: Also: update your question and show us the CSS definition for the appliedFilter_banned class

Comment: Does the <UL> element fire change events?

Comment: #filter_banned is a `<input type="checkbox">`.  If I put things like alert or Console.Debug in there, I can see them, so I know the event fired.

Comment: @MiffTheFox: I've had better luck with the click jQuery event for checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be mis-reading something here, but isn't this line:

```
$("#admin-userList").removeClass("appliedFilter_banned");
```

just removing the class you wanted set straight away?

Comment: Thank you.  I had assumed there was an else there.

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing something, but it looks like you're adding the class `"appliedFilter_banned"`, and then immediately removing it. Are you missing an `else`?

Answer (score 3):

Attention, you should write correctly the IF:

```
$("#filter_banned").change(function(){

  var ul = $("#admin-userList");

  if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
    ul.addClass("appliedFilter_banned");
  } else {    
    ul.removeClass("appliedFilter_banned");
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the click event handler instead of change.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$("#filter_banned").change(function(){


$("#filter_banned").is(':checked') ? $("#admin-userList").hide(): $("#admin-userList").show();

})
```